# Getting assembly attributes with Roslyn

Tags: c#, attributes, roslyn

I want to be able to read some assembly attributes from the AssemblyInfo.cs file in an assembly using the Roslyn code analysis.

So given the following sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

[assembly: Helloworld.TestAttribute1("Test1")]
[assembly: Helloworld.TestAttribute1(TheValue = "Test1", IgnoreThis = "I dont want this one!")]

namespace Helloworld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class TestAttribute1 : Attribute
    {
        public TestAttribute1()
        {
        }

        public TestAttribute1(string theValue)
        {
            this.TheValue = theValue;
        }

        public string TheValue { get; set; }

        public string IgnoreThis { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to extract the attribute of type `TestAttribute1` and the value of defined property named `TheValue`.

This is defined twice in the example - first using the constructor parameter, and the other using a named parameter.

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string cs = GetFile();

        SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(cs);

        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("").AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

        // get the attributes

        AttributeSyntax attr1 = root.DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<AttributeSyntax>().ToArray()[0];
        AttributeSyntax attr2 = root.DescendantNodes()
                .OfType<AttributeSyntax>().ToArray()[1];

        var ex1 = attr1.ArgumentList.Arguments.FirstOrDefault().Expression as LiteralExpressionSyntax;
        var str1 = ex1.GetText().ToString();

        var ex2 = attr2.ArgumentList.Arguments.FirstOrDefault().Expression as LiteralExpressionSyntax;
        var str2 = ex2.GetText().ToString();

}
```

Currently I am cheating a little by just hard coding locating the assembly attributes.  Again hard coding the `ArgumentList` to get the first expression in there.  This gets me the result for str1 and str2 to be `\"Test1\"`

Is there a way just to say, give me the attributes of type `TestAttribute1` then say, give me the value of the property named `TheValue`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achive that just try to get attributes from `IAssemblySymbol`,this symbol can be retrived from `Compilation`:

```
var attribute = compilation.Assembly.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeClass.ToString() == "Helloworld.TestAttribute1");
if(!(attribute is null))
{
    var ctorArgs = attribute.ConstructorArguments;
    var propArgs = attribute.NamedArguments;
}
```

`ctorArgs` and `propArgs` is a collection (`propArgs` is dictionary) of `TypedConstant` items and `TypedConstant` has property `Value` (or `Values` when it's array) that keeps the passed value as ctor argument or as property value. And finally, you just need to filter arguments that you are interesting using `TypedConstant.Type`.

This should look like the following:

```
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(cs);

var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("test").AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

// get references to add
compilation = compilation.AddReferences(GetGlobalReferences());

var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

var attrs = compilation.Assembly.GetAttributes().Where(x => x.AttributeClass.ToString() == "Helloworld.TestAttribute1");

foreach (var attr in attrs)
{
    var ctorArgs = attr.ConstructorArguments;
    var propArgs = attr.NamedArguments;
}
```

```
private static IEnumerable<MetadataReference> GetGlobalReferences()
{
    var assemblies = new[]
    {
        typeof(System.Object).Assembly, //mscorlib
    };

    var refs = from a in assemblies
        select MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(a.Location);

    return refs.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason if I run that the `attribute.ConstructorArguments` and `attr.NamedArguments` are empty.  This is same for both attributes if I iterate through instead of FirstOrDefault. **NOTE:**  This example is using dotnetcore 2.2.

Comment: @Andez, presumbly, the problem is that the compilation doesn't know that `TestAttribute1` is attribute, because compilation doesn't have reference to the system's libraries: `mscrolib`, `System`, `System.Core`. So try to add them

Comment: The missing arguments are probably caused by a compilation error. You should examine the diagnostics that are returned from compilation.GetDiagnostics().

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the attributes of a given type, the following code will work:

```
Func<AttributeSyntax, bool> findAttribute = (a) =>
{
    var typeInfo = model.GetTypeInfo(a).ConvertedType;
    return typeInfo.Name == "TestAttribute1" && typeInfo.ContainingNamespace.Name == "Helloworld";
};

AttributeSyntax[] attrs = root.DescendantNodes()
    .OfType<AttributeSyntax>()
    .Where(findAttribute)
    .ToArray();
```